# How to validate and know if an URL is a Google Docs URL? |Python,Flask|

Tags: python, validation, flask, url, google-docs

I'm creating a website that has a function to let user share their Google Docs URL to each others. I want to validate the input of the user to be Google Docs URL before I let them post it so that it could be safe. I'm using Flask and Python and I wonder if there is anyway to validate this.

The only validations I learn so far are those from FlaskForm like below:

```
project_link = StringField('Google Docs link to your project', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

and to limits the URL's character to 100 in my models.py

I think a possible way to do it is to create some Python codes in my views.py that check if the URL contains phrases like "docs.google.com"...

I don't really know how to validate if an URL is a Google Docs URL and I would greatly appreciate it if you could show me how.

Thank you.

Comment: What about [txt.find](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp)?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```py
url = "http://docs.google.com/an/example/google/doc"
prefixes = ["https://","http://"]

def validate(url):
    for pre in prefixes:
        url = url.strip(pre) # this gets rid of http or https prefixes
        if url.startswith("docs.google.com"):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This also has the effect of filtering out any unwanted prefixes, such as "chrome://" or "about://".

An example:

```
>>> url = "http://docs.google.com/document"
>>> validate(url)
True
>>> url = "https://googledocs.com"
>>> validate(url)
False
>>> url = "prefix://docs.google.com"
>>> validate(url)
False
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! :) Do you think @E-A solution below is better than yours? (I just wanted to know which solution is more secure)

Comment: @Upchanges E-A's solution is not ideal, as it only checks to see if "docs.google.com" is in the string, and it could be anywhere in that string. From a neutral point of view, I would probably say that my one was more secure, also because of prefix evaluation.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I really appreciate it!  I will try your codes now:)

Comment: I chose my solution because its simpler (a one line if statement) but is there any actual difference as to whether or not you check is its at the beginning (i exclued `&site=` anyways)? As a side point, you should probably include `www` in your prefix list as well

Comment: @E-A a google docs URL should start with docs.google.com, not contain it at any point. And `www` is not a prefix, its's a subdomain which would be used if there was no `docs` in front of the base domain. So `www.google.com` would be used, but not `www.docs.google.com`.

Comment: www.docs,google.com is a valid google docs address that your code would return False to. Although obviously the docs.google.com should be at the start of the link (right after the prefixes) I don't think its simpler to remove the prefixes rather then allow the link to be in the middle, but ensure that workarounds still aren't possible.

Comment: @E-A yep sorry you're correct on the `www.` prefix, but if you copy a google docs link from your browser or use the google docs share link, they almost always start with `https://`. In fact if it doesn't, it might be a good idea for the validation to reject it, because  HTTP Secure is normally the recommended link type. Either way, having "docs.google.com" somewhere in the URL string is too weak a validation to actually prevent any dangerous or incorrect URLs

Comment: just `docs.google.com` is only a problem because you can br redirected with `prev= ... & site=...` . With a check in place for that isn't better to have smaller, compact code which accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: @E-A anyone can put any URL with any combination of args in the URL query string. Just checking for two, `prev` and `site`, won't validate the URL. For example, `microsoft.com/hello?x=docs.google.com`, `stackoverflow.com/docs.google.com?name=hello` and `youtube.com/watch?v=docs.google.com` will **all** evaluate to `True`, because they contain the string "docs.google.com", yet they are not Google Docs URLs

Comment: Fair enough. I never thought about them being arguments in a URL, your answer is definitely more complete

Comment: @E-A the only problem with mine is, as you said, the `www` prefix. I suppose you could add that to the prefixes list, but you would have to position it in the list **after** any `http://` or `https://` prefixes, because the list is looped through in order and would have to strip off those before getting to the `www` prefix.

Comment: Thats actually not a problem at all, but it has shown another problem with your code. You have indented your `if-else` loop into the `for` loop, meaning even an `http://` would return `False`. If you move the loop back one indent, and make sure to put `www.` at the *end* of the list, your code works

Comment: @E-A yes, you are correct. Although I'm not sure if anyone actually prepends `www.` to a subdomain, but yes, if could do with being touched up a tad.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL='www......'
if 'docs.google.com' in URL and '&site=' not in URL:
    print(True)
```

As  monsieuralfonse64 pointed out, you need the second half of the statement to prevent bypasses where the *previous* page is listed as containing docs.google.com, but not the other site.

This answer is WRONG. as was once again pointed out, any number of prefixes could be in front of a link, and anything from `microsoft.com/hello?x=docs.google.com` to `stackoverflow.com/docs.google.com?name=hello` and `youtube.com/watch?v=docs.google.com` would all be validated in my approach.

Comment: This would work, but the only issue is that someone could have a dodgy URL like this: `http://example.com?prev=docs.google.com&site=dodgysite.com` and as long as the string "docs.google.com" is in it, it will evaluate to true

Comment: well spotted! I've introduced a check to prevent that from happening

Comment: maybe if 'https://docs.google.com' in URL and ... ?

Comment: This works! Thank you!:) But I needed to change the "and "in the if statement to "or"

Comment: Why would you want it to be an `or` ? as  monsieuralfonse64 pointed out, the site `http://example.com?prev=docs.google.com&site=dodgysite.com` would still get past if its an or (it does have `docs.google.com` in, but since it has `&site=` you still want to exclude it.

Comment: You probably can't just look if the name is in the url, because you can encode url in alot of different weird ways. So even looking if the name is found before a question mark won't work, because that could just get encoded.

Comment: @DutchJelly but if the name is encoded, maybe it's a good idea for the server to not accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more solution to these already good solutions. For stuff like this you can always just use existing libraries!

Existing libraries probably are accounting for some corner-cases that you haven't thought of yourself (if you chose the right one). We don't want ot re-invent the wheel now, do we?

Here's how I would go about it:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "https://drive.google.nl"
format = "drive.google.com"

parsed = urlparse(url)
if(parsed.netloc == format and (parsed.scheme == "http" or parsed.scheme == "https")):
    print(True)
```

I only tested this in python3, but I'm sure it'll also work for other python versions.

Comment: On the subject or URL parsing libraries, you can actually do this Werkzeug's own `url` library, which comes with flask (werkzeug is the base of flask, it's the development server that runs on `flask run`, it manages ports etc)